# bootstrap 3 Button not working in IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, button

Here is the button design i have used:

```
 <a href="editpage.php?id=6"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Endre</button></a>&nbsp;
```

The button works in all browsers except IE11 (don't know regarding other versions IE), I can't find out why. I'm using Bootstrap 3.
I've included bootstrap.js and IE8 support for HTML5 elements and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why dont you try adding the css classes to the anchor instead of adding unnecessarily button element?

```
<a href="editpage.php?id=6" class="btn btn-primary">Endre</a>&nbsp;
```

Comment: Have u included bootstrap css ?

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

Checked in IE10 Working Fine

Comment: What's exactly not working with this button on IE11 ?